# How to change the Python version in Azure Machine Learning sdk ContainerImage with CondaDependencies

Tags: docker, conda, azure-machine-learning-service

I am trying to get my Faster R-CNN model into an Container Instance on ACI. For that I need my docker image to posses python version 3.5.*. I specify that in my conda yaml file, but every time I spin an instance up and `docker run -it *** /bin/bash` into it I see that it only has Python 3.6.7.

https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/21140767/50680590-82b20b80-1008-11e9-9bfe-4a0e71084ce0.png

How can I get my Docker image to have Python version 3.5.*? I already tried conda installing Python version 3.5.2, but that didn't work as eventually it didn't posses 3.5.2, but only 3.6.7. (dfimage lets you see the dockerfile from which the image was created, https://hub.docker.com/r/chenzj/dfimage/).

https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/21140767/50680673-d6245980-1008-11e9-9d48-71a7c150d925.png

My yaml:

```
name: project_environment
dependencies:
- python=3.5.2

- pip:
  - matplotlib
  - opencv-python==3.4.3.18
  - azureml-core==1.0.6
  - numpy
  - cntk
  - cython
channels:
- anaconda
```

Notebook cell:
    from azureml.core.conda_dependencies import CondaDependencies

```
svmandss = CondaDependencies.create(python_version="3.5.2", pip_packages=[
    "matplotlib",
    "opencv-python==3.4.3.18",
    "azureml-core",
    "numpy",
    "cntk",
    "cython"], )
svmandss.add_channel('anaconda')

with open("fasterrcnn.yml","w") as f:
    f.write(svmandss.serialize_to_string())
```

Another notebook cell with ContainerImage specifications.

```
image_config = ContainerImage.image_configuration(execution_script="score_fasterrcnn.py",runtime="python",conda_file="./fasterrcnn.yml",dependencies=listdir("utils"),docker_file="./Dockerfile")

service = Webservice.deploy_from_model(workspace=ws,
                                       name='faster-rcnn',
                                       deployment_config=aciconfig,
                                       models=[Model(workspace=ws, name='Faster-RCNN')],
                                       image_config=image_config)

service.wait_for_deployment(show_output=True)
```

### Note

For better readability see my GitHub issue: (https://github.com/Azure/MachineLearningNotebooks/issues/163).

Comment: My apologies. I see it has already been removed. Thank you.

Comment: The question itself looks OK, but I think you received -4 for the title. You could try deleting this and re-posting it, since this one may now not get very many views.

Comment: There is a step in Dockerfile that is as follows: `Step 13/16 : RUN sed -i '/^\s*-\s*python\s*[<>=]/d' '/var/azureml-app/conda.yaml' && cat '/var/azureml-app/conda.yaml'`. So it is impossible to define which version of Python is going to be used. I guess that it was made to prevent problems with other versions but, for instance, for me it is a big issue since I only can build MLFlow images with 3.5.2 or 3.7.3 in Databricks with involves to "unknown opcode" error when deploying the image.

Comment: @FernandoOrtega, thanks for this hint. I was banging my head on this for hours.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, the version of Python is fixed to what's in Azure ML's base image, when deploying the web service. We're investigating removing this limitation in future.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is one of the top Google answers when searching for "azureml python version" I'm posting the answer here. The documentation is not very clear when it comes to this, but the following will work:

```py
from azureml.core import Workspace


from azureml.core.runconfig import RunConfiguration
from azureml.core.conda_dependencies import CondaDependencies

ws = Workspace.from_config()

# This is the important part
conda_dep = CondaDependencies(conda_dependencies_file_path="pipeline/environment.yml")
aml_run_config = RunConfiguration(conda_dependencies=conda_dep)

# Define compute target - must be preconfigured in th workspace
compute_target = ws.compute_targets['my-azureml-target']
aml_run_config.target = compute_target


from azureml.pipeline.steps import PythonScriptStep
script_source_dir = "./pipeline"
step_1_script = "test.py"

step_1 = PythonScriptStep(
    script_name=step_1_script,
    source_directory=script_source_dir,
    compute_target=compute_target,
    runconfig=aml_run_config,
    allow_reuse=True
)

from azureml.pipeline.core import Pipeline

# Build the pipeline
pipeline1 = Pipeline(workspace=ws, steps=[step_1])

from azureml.core import Experiment

# Submit the pipeline to be run
pipeline_run1 = Experiment(ws, 'Test-pipeline').submit(pipeline1)
pipeline_run1.wait_for_completion(show_output=True)
```

This assumes the following directory structure:

- root/

  - create_pipeline.py
  - pipeline/

    - test.py
    - environment.yml

where create_pipeline.py is the file above, test.py is the script you would like to run and environment.yml is the conda environment file - including the python version.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to change the Python version by registering the environment in Azure ML Workspace:

```
from azureml.core.environment import Environment, Workspace
environment = Environment.from_conda_specification(name='myenv', file_path='environment.yml')
environment.python.user_managed_dependencies = False
workspace = Workspace.from_config()
environment = environment.register(workspace=workspace)
env_build = environment.build(workspace=workspace)
```

Then, configure the endpoint for publishing as follows:

```
from azureml.core.model import InferenceConfig
environment = Environment.get(workspace=workspace, name='myenv')
inference_config = InferenceConfig(
    entry_script='inference.py',
    source_directory='.',
    environment=environment
)
```

This is using Azure ML SDK 1.29.0. Perhaps this has already been fixed and the original method works as well, but I didn't test that.

Answer (score -1):

EDIT:

This is no longer an issue for me. I found another way to get my code to work with python version 3.6.7.

This is however still an issue if you ask me. If in the future I do need python version 3.5 then there will not be a solution as of now.

You can still post an answer if you would like.