# specify python version in azureml image

Tags: python, azure, version, conda, databricks

I'm deploying a model using azureml. The databricks environment uses python 3.5.2 and the deployed image 3.6.8 and causes the model to crash. When creating the image, I define my conda_environment like this:

```
myenv = CondaDependencies.create(python_version='3.5.2',
                                 pip_packages=['azureml-core==1.0.41',
                                               'numpy==1.16.3','scikit-learn==0.20.3'])
```

However when I deploy the image, I print the python version and the image has 3.6.8. Is there any other way I could get the image to use 3.5.2?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want to use `Python 3.5.2` to create a `CondaDependencies` object, but seems that your current Python version is `3.6.8`.

Just according to your description, I don't know what your environment is and how to do. However, I assumed that you followed the offical document [`Quickstart: Use your own notebook server to get started with Azure Machine Learning`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/service/quickstart-run-local-notebook) to do, so the first thing is to make sure that you have installed the Python runtime `3.5.2` in your Anaconda environment. For that, you can refer to the Anaconda FAQ topic [`How do I get Anaconda with Python 3.5 or 3.6?`](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/faq/#anaconda-faq-35) as the figure below.

[image]

```
$ conda install python=3.5
```

Or download and install Anaconda [`4.2.0`](https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/) instead of your current one.

Then, you can create a virutal env with Python 3.5.2.

```
$ conda create -n <your env name> -y Python=3.5  
$ conda activate <your env name>
$ conda install nb_conda  
$ pip install azureml-sdk[notebooks]  
$ jupyter notebook
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **set_python_version** method available in azureml.core.conda_dependencies class to set your desired python version. As you have already created an object myenv of the same class, you can set the version as below

```
    myenv.set_python_version('3.5.2')
```

Comment: I see this answer is a few years old, so it could be that the SDK changed, but for me I needed myenv.python.conda_dependencies.set_python_version('3.5.2').  Regardless, this answer was very helpful.  Thanks for posting!

Answer (score 0):

You can define a CondaDependencies instance that you pass to a RunConfiguration instance when you initialize it. See details here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64133648/787267